# Accent support for mails in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I'm sending a mail with the word Òmnium (see the accent) in the sender using Spring Framework.

The code is the one I found for Spring:

```
    org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl sender = sender();
    javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage msg = sender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, multipart, "UTF-8");
    helper.setFrom(from);
    ...
    sender.send(msg);
```

I've tried two approaches:

1. No handling to from
2. Encode with : `MimeUtility.encodeText(from)` or `MimeUtility.encodeText(from, "UTF-8", null)`

The first case gives me a question mark. The second one gives a `=?UTF-8?Q?=C3=92mnium`, as seen in Thunderbird.

What is the right approach?

Comment: The right approach is adding "Q" encoding : MimeUtility.encodeText(from, "UTF-8","Q")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach works fine. Note that you shouldn't apply `MimeUtility.encodeText()`  to the address part of the `From` field, i. e.

```
String from = MimeUtility.encodeText("Òmnium", "UTF-8", null) + " <test@test.com>";
```